# Countable or uncountable

Tags: combinatorics, cardinals

(1) $C$ is the set of all circles $C(z,r)$ with $z\in\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ and $r\in\mathbb{Q}^+$. What is the cardinality of $C$?

(2) Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $X=\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $X_n\in\{0,1,2\}$ for all $n$.  Show that $S$ is uncountable.

(3) A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a proper local maximum at $a$ if there exists an interval $(b,c)$ such that $b<a<c$ and $f(x)<f(a)$ for all $b<x<c$, $x\neq a$. Denoting by $M$ the set of all proper local maxima, show that $M$ is countable.

No clue for these, any hint?

Comment: Your part (3) is not a complete sentence? What makes you stuck? (It is easier to provide good hints if we know more precisely why you are stuck)

Comment: @Stahl How did you know that was what the last part was supposed to be?

Comment: I just turned a period into a comma. When I went to edit, there was more substance there than originally appeared (I didn't actually do anything besides fix a sentence and improve LaTeX).

Comment: @Stahl Ahh, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), the number of possible centres of circles is countable and the number of possible radii is countable. What does that mean for the set $C$?

For (2), are you familiar with [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)? It's very similar to what you're trying to show.

For (3), edit: just see the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINTS:

1. You have one circle for each triple $\langle p,q,r\rangle\in\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q^+$. You know that $\Bbb Q$ is countable. What do you know about the cardinality of $S\times S$ when $S$ is countable?
2. Look at the subset $Y$ of $X$ consisting of just the sequences whose terms are all $0$ or $1$. If $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is such a sequence, let $A_y=\{n\in\Bbb N:y_n=1\}$. Show that the map $y\mapsto A_y$ is a bijection from $Y$ to $\wp(\Bbb N)$. Is $\wp(\Bbb N)$ countable, or uncountable?
3. You know that for each $a\in M$ there are $b_a<a$ and $c_a>a$ such that $f(x)<f(a)$ whenever $b_a<x<a$ or $a<x<c_a$. You can always choose $b_a$ and $c_a$ to be rational numbers. (Why?) Assume that we’ve done so. There are only countably many pairs $\langle p,q\rangle$ of rational numbers with $p<q$. (Why?) Thus, $\{\langle b_a,c_a\rangle:a\in M\}$ is countable. If $M$ is uncountable, that means that there must be some pair $\langle p,q\rangle$ of rational numbers such that $b_a=p$ and $c_a=q$ for uncountably many points $a\in M$. Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be distinct points of $(p,q)\cap M$. Explain why we must have both $f(a_1)<f(a_2)$ and $f(a_2)<f(a_1)$. Of course this is impossible, so when you’ve done all that, you’ll have shown that $M$ cannot be uncountable and must therefore be countable.

Comment: For1, I know that since Q is countable, QxQxQ+is also countable, but what is the cardinality?

Comment: @Elvis: If you know that $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q^+$ is countable, then you already know everything that you need to know for (1): you know that $C$ is countable. Since $C$ is clearly infinite, you have your answer: $C$ is countably infinite. If you need to express that symbolically, you can say that the cardinality of $C$ is $\omega$ or $\aleph_0$; both notations are correct.